# iOS - multiple selection

Tags: gui-design, ios, selection, multi-selection

I have 3 values - A, B and C. The values can be selected in the following ways:

1. Select A only
2. Select A and B
3. Select A, B and C

<s>The values used for A, B and C are large enough to not fit on screen.</s>

Every value used for A, B and C are large enough to fit almost all horizontal space in screen.

What kind of UIView is better to achieve this goal? I was thinking about a vertical switch but I have no idea how to re-design a UIView.

Comment: I'm confused, what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question.

Comment: a vertical switch sounds good, with a being selected when b is selected, and b being selected when c is selected.

Comment: What do you mean with "not fit on screen"? Horizontally? or the whole screen?

Comment: @rr1g0 I have updated the question.

Comment: It really depends on the context, so what is this value - is it bananas or what? Maybe there is a compact way of displaying these variables. What is the process users try to complete when they have to choose one of these 3 values? Who are the users? Without this information we are shooting in the air.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a short explanation of what your choices are, and leave a lot of room for one the explanation at the time.  See example.

[image]

I think Nathan's response is on the right place with removing the "multiple" selection idea, but just a radio button kind of thing is not appropriate for a mobile, specially if you don't have enough room horizontally.

Answer (score 8):

**Keep it simple: use radio buttons.**

Checkboxes and your rules governing what can be selected and when will be confusing for both your users and programmers alike. Someone will try to select only option B and you'll either have to explain to them that it's not allowed or set up conditions to only allow B after A. (But then what happens if they deselect A?)

All that complication is unnecessary for what is essentially a choice between 3 options. Radio buttons should work nicely. Users will also benefit from having the three options enumerated for them instead of having to puzzle through what is allowed and what is not.

Example:
[image: Example picture with ice cream.]

Comment: Why not check boxes? Seems like you're adding to and subtracting

Comment: Because checkboxes mean more than one option can be selected and each can be selected equally. That's not true in this case. B can never be selected alone, and A without B or C is subtly different from A and B but not C. This is the unnecessary complication I was referring two.

Comment: It could be: do you want anything with your ice cream?

Comment: [] Nuts [] hot fudge

Comment: That is a possible answer if 100% of users will be getting ice cream/option A. The way the question is written it seems like they need people to select or confirm that they do want ice cream/option A. It would depend on the context of the question.

Comment: I mean... from his question, option a was always going to be an option.

Comment: The OP suggests that the option names are long so this may look awkward but I think this is still a decent option.

Comment: Maybe I understand something different from the OP, but isn't he asking to allow multiple values (hence, a checkbox is needed)?

Comment: The ordering and wording seem confusing.  Why not `1) Ice cream` `2) Ice cream with hot fudge` `3) Ice cream with hot fudge and nuts`.  That way, going down the list, options are added, not removed.  Also, I think `x with y and NOT Z` is equivalent to `x with y`.

Comment: @HarrisonPaine Sure. Without knowing the real content I was just trying to copy the example in the question. Depending on the real context you may or may not need to emphasize that something is not included.

Comment: @NathanRabe Anyone of the this values are large enough fit almost all horizontal screen.

Comment: Radio buttons are not an option offered in iOS. The closest option is a segment control, but this does not work well for long fields. Generally tables are the standard as in the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

No B check box until they select A
No C check box until they select A and B

Comment: No A checkbox at all, since he doesn't say they are allowed to *not* select A.  ;)

Comment: @Wildcard You read "Select only A" different than I do

Comment: A value is always selected.

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking somewhere on the lines of **one** vertical slider that also gives feedback as you drag its range.

[image: Range slider for value A]
[image: Range slider for value A+B]
[image: Range slider for value A+B+C]

I created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chechs/8fcvasLf/) demonstrating this.

Comment: I think this is the best approach but I have not clue how do this in storyboard.

Comment: +1  But as a nobody, my first impression from your answer was that you had a crazy scheme of 3 sliders.  I then checked out your jsFiddle and was like, "oh, cool!"

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski My bad; I tend to think more on the lines of a developer. Updated to reflect it

Answer (score 2):

You need to use checkboxes if you are doing multiple selection. Selecting the checkbox given for the value selects the option and a provided button confirms all the selections made.

It seems you are actually accumulating options rather than allowing for multiple selection. You can modify the checkbox pattern to do allow for this by doing the following modifications:

1. Since A must always be selected provide only 2 options - B and C. You must of course inform the user of this somehow. Alternatively, if you want to show all three options in the list, you can have A selected but greyed out so the user cannot deselect it.
2. When the user selects C, automatically select B and have it greyed out so the user cannot deselect it. Again, you must explain to the user why the automatic selections are occurring.
3. When the user selects B, you don't have to do any additional work since A is already selected by default.

Comment: I was thinking use a range selector.

Comment: @Ricardo why a range selector? If you have discrete options that the user needs to select and the options don't lie along a range I wouldn't use a range selector.

Comment: **if** he is accumulating options, then I think this is the right answer. Not sure though since the question isn't very clear

Comment: @Devin I think it's fair to assume it's accumulation given range selector was an option for the OP, there are three options and only three possible selections and of course the other answers.

Comment: yes, it wasn't clear for me at first if he would be able to select C and A

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mockup based on @Papparazzi's answer:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fypUhF.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>